# Negation of Definition Help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logic

If $\boldsymbol{y}' = A\boldsymbol{y}$ where A is a $k \times k$ constant coefficient matrix.

*Stablility Definition*:

$\boldsymbol{y_0}$ is a stable equilibrium solution if for every $\epsilon > 0$ and any $t_0 > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0 $

such that if $|\boldsymbol{\psi(t_0)} - \boldsymbol{y_0}| < \delta$ where $\boldsymbol{\psi(t)}$ is any other solution to the system,

then $\boldsymbol{\psi(t)}$ exists for all $t \geq t_0$,  and

$|\boldsymbol{\psi(t)} - \boldsymbol{y_0}| < \epsilon$ for all $t \geq t_0$

*What is definition of an Unstable equilibrium solution?*

So far I have: (Unsure about bolded parts)

$\boldsymbol{y_0}$ is an unstable equilibrium solution if there exists $\epsilon > 0$ and **there exists** a $t_0 > 0$

such that for all $\delta > 0$ **there exists** another solution $\boldsymbol{\psi(t)}$ with $|\boldsymbol{\psi(t_0)} - \boldsymbol{y_0}| < \delta$ and

$|\boldsymbol{\psi(t)} - \boldsymbol{y_0}| \geq \epsilon$

Comment: What you are looking for is the *negation* of the condition in the definition of stability, which is *not* the same as "unstability".

Comment: @Jack I mean to say that a solution is unstable if it is not stable. So using the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of stability, is this definition of unstable correct?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Linear Time-Invariant system (LTI) such as ${\bf y}' = A{\bf y}$, then:

> The equilibrium $\bf{y_0}$ is asymptotically stable iff the real parts of all the eigenvalues of $A$ are negative.
>
> The equilibrium $\bf{y_0}$ is (marginally) stable iff the real parts of all the eigenvalues of $A$ are non positive.
>
> The equilibrium $\bf{y_0}$ is unstable iff there is at least one eigenvalue of $A$ such that its real part is positive.

Moreover:

1. The vector $[0 ~ 0 ~ \ldots 0]$ is always an equilibrium of the system above;
2. If there is more than one equilibrium, then you have infinite equilibrium points. Of course, $[0 ~ 0 ~ \ldots 0]$ is one of the infinite equilibrium points.
3. When you have infinite equilibrium points, then the rank of $A$ is not full. This means that at least one eigenvalue of $A$ is $0$. Indeed ${\bf y_0}$ is an equilibrium iff $A{\bf y_0} = {\bf 0}$. In this very case, you can have only marginal stability or instability.

Comment: I am looking for the definition of instability specifically in terms of $\epsilon-\delta$.